# I keep running out of memory and swapping but having a hard time figuring out what is using so much ram

Tags: ram, 18.10, memory-usage

This is what it looks like on top:

[image]

To get that free memory I had to kill Android Studio. Chrome is definitely using the most memory, but also Firefox. I keep both open most of the day doing different things. I've been doing that plus Android Studio for years and never had an issue until recently. The only thing I've changed recently is I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10. I noticed the buff/cache is really high, should it really be using that much when I'm running out of memory for applications and having to swap?

Edit: In the end it turned out that I had a couple of problems. The swap file was tiny but once I fixed that it would just take longer to run out of memory. Then I found out the Google Play Music Chrome extension was using a lot of memory, removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: You might look at some of the techniques in [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253816/restrict-size-of-buffer-cache-in-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253816/restrict-size-of-buffer-cache-in-linux)

Comment: Your swap space is too small. And the parameter vm.swappiness may need to be tweaked. The buff/cache is used as file/disk cache when available.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks for the link, going to play with those values.

Comment: @heynnema yeah just noticed that about my swap space, it has been like that for a while but I'll see if I can increase it. Still seems odd that it would prefer to swap rather than free up some ram on the buff/cache.

Comment: Hence my comment about tweaking vm.swappiness.

Comment: @heynnema I'm trying that as well, we'll see if it helps.

Comment: Just realized my swap partition isn't being mounted, at least not the right one, because I have 22 gigs for swap on my drive.

Comment: 22G is probably a little excessive for swap. Check your /etc/fstab for swap mount commands.

Comment: Ask the system what swap it has with `swapon`. `man swapon` will show youi how `root` can add swap space.

Comment: @waltinator The OP currently is using a 2G swap (you can see that via the `top` command output), but also has a 22G swap that's not being used (we don't know why yet). 2G is too small. 22G is too large. I'm not sure that swapon can be used to ADD swap.

Comment: I figured it out, Ubuntu I guess configures itself to use a swapfile. I made it grow a bit, so far working well. Thanks for the help. If you want to add it as answer I will gladly mark it as correct.

Comment: I think original poster has been running into some bug or special situation.  3920MB free, 14GB buff/mem but only 5764MB available, which means around 12GB buff/cache is in-use and cannot be freed, against normal situation.  32GB should be enough for Chrome, Firefox, and Android Studio.

Comment: @AlvinLiang it does seem odd to me. I actually increased my swap file significantly when I figured out it was too small and now there is 0 free on the new swap file, so I think something is leaking or something but I have no idea how to figure that out.

Comment: Think I figured it out, the Google Play Music Chrome extension was leaking memory, all my problems went away when I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

*Your 2G swap space is too small. And the parameter vm.swappiness may need to be tweaked. The buff/cache is used as file/disk cache when available.*

You thought the system was using a 22G swap partition, but instead it was using a 2G swapfile. You've enlarged that, and so far it's working well. I'd recommend about a 8G swapfile.

The parameter `vm.swappiness` can be changed from its default of 60, to 10, to see if that improves the ratio of main memory vs swap and disk/file cache. Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add `vm.swappiness=10`, and then reboot.